# Turning paragraph count in MS word into a useable Variable for looping

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a macro that lifts a selected amount of text from Document A, pastes it into document B, polls Word for the total number of paragraphs in document B, then does a routine to that text in document B, and when the routine is finished, copies the revised text back to document A. When it does this, it leaves behind remnants of text in doc A I want removed. (relevant portion of macro posted below)
The macro determines # of paragraphs, and then deletes a set amount of table rows in document A based on the # of paragraphs located in doc B. I get an error on line  and it has me stumped.
What is wrong with my code?

```
Sub info3()
Selection.WholeStory
Dim k As Integer

Dim AD As Document
Dim DP As Object

Set AD = ActiveDocument
Set DP = AD.BuiltInDocumentProperties

' Returns the number of paragraphs and lines in a document.
MsgBox "There are " & DP("Number Of Paragraphs") & _
  " paragraphs containing text " & "and " & DP("Number Of Lines") & _
  " lines counted."
  'top of page
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
'remove a row from a table an amount of times determined by # of paragraphs
' if 8 paragraphs detected, do this procedure 4 times.
'following line gets an error statement. Why?
Do Until k > (DP / 2)
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Rows.Delete
k = k + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What line do you get an error on?

Answer (score 0):

DP is an object not a number so you can't divide by 2. You need to store the number of paragraphs in a new variable

```
Dim numParagraphs as Integer

numParagraphs = DP("Number Paragraphs")
```

And use that in your loop.

Additionally you are mixing Table and Text properties. [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196543%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is a table property you would need to be within a table to delete a row. Also you have to use an index to access a specific row. For example

```
Selection.Rows(1).Delete
```

You could clear the selected text with something like:

```
Selection.Text = ""
```

But I don't know if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Originally, I got an error on line "Do until k> (DP/2). After adding Brad's 2 lines in, I get an error on numParagraphs = DP("Number Paragraphs") both with, and without the ("Number Paragraphs") text.All I'm trying to do, is turn the number of paragraphs detected into the seed of a For-Next loop. If there are 8 paragraphs detected by Word, fo a subroutine 4 times.....

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: My text to be deleted is indeed in a table. I've tried to leave out some info, so that this is a more generic useful question. The macro is LENGTHY. So the real question remains: How do I autodetect # of paragraphs in doc B to use as a loop counter on text manipulation in Doc A (For Next? or For each? etc..)

Comment: @chrisG I pasted the code into Word and stepped through it in the debugger the only line that failed for me was the one with Rows. Try adding breakpoints and stepping through the code.

Comment: A commenter on a MS website helped me solve this...

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim AD As Document
    Dim DP As Object
    Dim LP As Long
    Set AD = ActiveDocument
    Set DP = AD.BuiltInDocumentProperties
    LP = DP("Number Of Paragraphs") / 2

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    ' if 8 paragraphs detected, do this procedure 4 times.

    Do Until k > LP
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Rows.Delete
    k = k + 1
    Loop
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

A commenter on a MS website helped me solve this...

```
Dim k As Integer
Dim AD As Document
Dim DP As Object
Dim LP As Long
Set AD = ActiveDocument
Set DP = AD.BuiltInDocumentProperties
LP = DP("Number Of Paragraphs") / 2

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

' if 8 paragraphs detected, do this procedure 4 times.

Do Until k > LP
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Rows.Delete
k = k + 1
Loop
End Sub
```